# VBA inverte dia com mês nas variáveis do tipo Date

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, data, excel-vba, visual-basic-6

**Contexto:** tenho o seguinte código que recebe do usuário uma data:

```
dataAtualDefault = Day(Date) & "/" & Month(Date) & "/" & Year(Date)
dataInsercao = Application.InputBox("Data da entrada", "Entrada", dataAtualDefault)
```

**Problema:** caso o usuário cometa um typo e insira uma data em que o mês seja maior que 12, como, por exemplo, 09/15/2020, o valor do mês é invertido com o do dia, e a variável passa a ter o seguinte valor: 15/09/2020

**Soluções que já tentei mas não deram certo:**

1. Essa não deu certo porque o mês e dia são invertidos antes do `If`

```
    If(Month(dataInsercao ) > 12) Then
        MsgBox("Erro!")
    End If
```

2. `Format` não me ajuda pois converte para uma String, mas eu realmente preciso que a variável seja do tipo Date

```
Format(dataInsercao , "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: Não é isso, é que a data está no Americano que é `mês/dia/ano`, o que você vai fazer com a data?

Comment: Sim, é no formato estadunidense. Mas como remover isso?
A data fornecida pelo usuário será inserida numa coluna com várias outras data. Então, a data inserida pelo usuário é compara com as demais para saber se deve ser feita a organização ordenada de todas as datas

Comment: se está inserindo aonde? ta confusa sua pergunta

Comment: A data é inserida numa coluna do excel

Answer (score 0):

testei o codigo e nao aparece esse erro...
se estas a inserir numa célula do excel tenta formatar primeiro essa célula para data.
`With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B1") .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" .Value = Date End With`

Answer (score -2):

Encontrei uma solução para o problema. Insira os dados assim no excel:
Sheets("Exemplo").Cells(1, 1).Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 0, VBA.Format(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy"))

Funciona 100%

Answer (score -2):

Na Tela (Form) Não use ".Value" no TextBox, só use na planilha (célula) se quiser salvar.
EX:
Textbox1 = Date 'Atualiza a DATA na Tela(Form).
Range("TABELAS!P5").Value = Textbox1 'Salva a Data na ABA:"TABELAS" célula "P5".

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).